# Python Beginner: How to Extract data from selected row from a website table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, row

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = ('http://texaset.tamu.edu/')
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
#table = soup.find_all('table')
gdata = soup.find_all('td',{"class":"Data"})
for item in gdata:
  print(item.text)
```

---

This is the code for extracting the data from the website
after executing code output is similar to this:
Conroe
0.12
58
45
28
15.76
0.00
4.70
6.06

Huntsville
0.10
56
41
27
16.21
0.00
2.10
3.57

Overton
0.12
53
35
42
16.34
0.00
7.52
16.89

But I need the data of only one city.. like this:

Conroe
0.12
58
45
28
15.76
0.00
4.70
6.06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are asking here, but my guess is, you are trying to extract the `text` from a table cell.

Have you tried `print(gdata.text)`

**EDIT 1**

If the CSS selectors are same for all the cells, and thinking that there might be more than 2 lines of extracted data, and the desired data can be anywhere on the table; I suggest extract them all to a list and than search for `Conroe` As;

```
for item in List1:
    if item.startswith('Conroe'):
        print(item)
```

Comment: sorry for confusing question..Yes, I'm trying to extract "text" from whole table, but have a problem to get only one row of the table cell

Comment: tried but it throws "'NoneType' object is not callable"